# how can we give slider to background image using css?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style> 
  #example1 {
      background-image: url(img_flwr.gif), url(paper.gif), url(flower.gif);
      background-position: right bottom, left top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
      padding: 100px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="example1">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, I am using three background images i.e img_flwr.gif, paper.gif, flower.gif. I want to slide these image using css. I don't want to fade these images. So, how could I do this?

Comment: What attempt have you done to make this yourself?

Comment: You might want to use javascript for this because CSS is only for styling.

Comment: Do you want to set multiple background images? You should use `setInterval` and jQuery css http://api.jquery.com/css/  to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Make an image element and use `position: absolute` and `z-index` CSS property to set the image behind an another element. Then make your slider with JQuery.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style> 
#example1 {
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  padding: 100px;
  z-index: 10;

 }
#slider {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
 }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="example1">

  </div>
 <div id="slider">
 <img src="flwr.jpg" alt="Paris">
 <img src="paper.jpg" alt="Paris">
 <img src="flower.jpg" alt="Paris">
  </div>

<script>

</script>



</body>
</html>
```